# How can I check for an empty object within an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, object, nsarray

I'd like to check for an empty object (i.e. an object of an array which doesn't have a value) within an array which gets its data from a file.

As an example, if my array contains 12 objects (all NSString) and the object at index 11 doesn't return a value when its description is printed into the debug section of Xcode. I want to check if that is the case and respond accordingly. I already tried

```
if (!([MY_ARRAY objectAtIndex:11] == nil))
{
   //Some Stuff
}
else
{
  //Some other Stuff
}
```

which didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What sort of objects are in the array? If one returns an empty string then it's for a reason specific to that type of object. E.g. if it's an `NSString` (which return themselves as their description) then it may just be the empty string.

Comment: Just strings, but wouldn't an empt string return @"" and not absolutely nothing?

Comment: You can check the length of the string: [string length] > 0

Comment: Define "empty".  Empty string, empty dictionary, empty array, empty set???

Comment: @KJA1582 no, it wouldn't. The thing returned by `description` and therefore output by `NSLog` is a description of the object. It is not the Objective-C syntax you would need to type to create the object. Can you imagine what something like `NSURLConnection` would have to supply as a description?

Comment: @HotLicks empyt as in empty string

Comment: @Tommy Thanks for the clarification, and no I can't imagine what `NSURLConnection`(whatever that is) would return as ist description.

Comment: There are several different ways to check for an empty string.  But an empty string *does* have a *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of the string: `[string length] > 0`

Answer (score 2):

The description method is for debugging. You should not use it in your program logic. What are these objects, and what do they contain? Can you modify the objects to add an "isEmpty" property?

If you use NSNull, you'd use code like this:

```
NSArray *array = @{@"String", @(4), [NSNull null], @"Another string");

for (id anObject in array)
{
  if (anObject =! [NSNull null]))
  {
     //Some Stuff
  }
  else
  {
    //Some other Stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an object is an array cannot be nil, but you can use [NSNull null] which is an "object equivalent" to nil

Comment: It still executed the if and not the else after replacing nil with [NSNull null]

Comment: I get following in the Debug console after printing the description of said object:

Printing description of [11]:
<object returned empty description>

Comment: If an object returns empty description, it just means it does not implement the description method. What is the class of the object if you `po` the object in console, or `NSLog` the object in code?

Comment: Using NSLog it just prints nothing, but what is po?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out. This is the result: (lldb) po 0x3faa29d0
<object returned empty description>

(lldb)

Comment: Can you show the code that fills the array? Or, are you just setting objects at given indexes leaving empty objects in between? (po - print object, just make a breakpoint and you can then print stuff in console, but you figured out already).

Comment: Part 1:
   NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self savefilepath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.flightplan", Flightnumber]]];
    
    NSArray *fileContents = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    fileContents = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil errorDescription:nil];

Comment: Part 2: NSString *RouteStr = [fileContents objectAtIndex:19];
        NSArray *Route = [RouteStr componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

Comment: You are assigning an `id` object into an immutable array fileContents. Do you get any objects from that call non nil, or are they all nil?

Comment: They are all non-nil, since that is just the content of a .plist, which in turn holds a string that i converted into the Route array with `componentsSeperatedByString`. Its the Route array which I work with.

Comment: @MartinKoles [string length] > 0 actually worked! If you wright that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As Jerome Diaz states, objects in an array can't be nil. The only option you have is to check the count property of the array if it reflects an expected value, or you can inspect the type/class of the object in the array. A safe way to include empty object into array is `[NSNull null]`, but this is the task for the method that fills the array, not the one that reads it.

You can check the class type of an object in array with `isKindOfClass` or `isMemberOfClass`.